# Organizing based on date - easiest/elegant way

Tags: php

Ok, I've got some code that creates an array, and then iterates over that array, and from one of the items, gets an id, and a title.

What I WOULD like, is to be able to organize based on date.

Now as you can see, I already grab the date per item, however there's no real easy way to organize based on it that I can see. I suppose I could pull the entity id, check the date on it, and put that in order, and then generate the additional data after that - would that be the simplest method?

```
$multi_reg_id = multi_reg_get_id();
  foreach ($multi_reg_id as $regid) {
    $node = node_load($regid->entity_id);
    $title = $node->title;
    $date = $node->field_event_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $entity_id = (string)$regid->entity_id;

    $dt = new DateTime($date);
    $date = $dt->format('l, F d, Y - g:ia');
    $checkbox[$entity_id] = $title . " | " . $date;
        }


return $checkbox;
```

Comment: Can you define `organize`? Do you mean sort in ascending/descending order, based on date? Do you mean key on date? Do you mean something else? What does `organize` mean in your context?

Comment: What does `node_load` do? Where are the `nodes` stored? Are you trying to `organize` the original `node` list that you are retrieving `nodes` from, or are you trying to organize some other list? `$checkbox` array perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the timestamps as an array key, then use `ksort` to sort. Finally, flatten the multidimmension with `call_user_func_array` and `array_merge`:

```
$multi_reg_id = multi_reg_get_id();

$output = array();
foreach ($multi_reg_id as $regid) {
    $node = node_load($regid->entity_id);
    $title = $node->title;
    $date = $node->field_event_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $entity_id = (string)$regid->entity_id;

    $dt = new DateTime($date);
    $date = $dt->format('l, F d, Y - g:ia');

    if (!array_key_exists($dt->getTimestamp(), $output))
        $output[$dt->getTimestamp()] = array();
    $output[$dt->getTimestamp()][$entity_id] = $title . " | " . $date;
}

ksort($output);
$output = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $output);

return $output;
```

**Documentation**

- `DateTime::getTimestamp` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php
- `array_merge` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php
- `call_user_func_array` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php
- `ksort` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php